# Share variable in SSDT pre and post deployment scripts

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

We're using SSDT to upgrade out databases, and I want to disable a feature (the value of which is stored in the db) which may or may not be enabled, and then re-set it to it's original value.

i.e.

```
Pre-Deployment
- Make a note of whether Property X is Enabled/Disabled
- Set Property X to Disabled

Deploy
- (Various Actions)

Post-Deployment
- Set Property X to the original value it was during Pre-Deployment
```

Presumably this is a relatively frequent pattern (in wix scripts it's called the remember property pattern), I'm just not sure how to do it as part of an SSDT Migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a table, in the pre-deploy script if no row insert the state then in the post-deploy read from the state and action and delete the row.

I would do it like that rather than just storing it so you guarantee that if it dies it will self-correct next time it runs.

Comment: Many thanks Ed. I was wondering f there was an in-built way of doing something like this, but yes, this would certainly work. Have some points, and nice blog btw :)